# How to parse multi-range request response

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm trying to send a range request with multiple ranges like the one described here: [HTTP/1.1 response to multiple range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315787/http-1-1-response-to-multiple-range). The problem is that I'm not able to parse the response correctly. How can I parse this using OkHttp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by following what's described in this answer [Receiving Multipart Response on client side (ClosableHttpResponse)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42548549/1351433).
I imported the below library:

> compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'

So my code is now like the following:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader("range", String.format("bytes=%s", TextUtils.join(", ", ranges)))
        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
ByteArrayDataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(response.body().byteStream(), response.body().contentType().toString());
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(dataSource);
int count = multipart.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
    if (bodyPart.isMimeType("application/octet-stream")) {
        processBinaryStream(bodyPart.getInputStream());
    } else {
        // Or process different types of data
        throw new Exception(String.format("Content type: %s cannot be parsed", bodyPart.getContentType()));
    }
}
```

I'm still not satisfied, having to import this whole mail handling library, just to manage multipart response. But for now, the problem is fixed till I find or come up with a better solution.